# Is there a better way to do this jQuery functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to bulk disable all the submit buttons present in my form. I am getting all the buttons using the following jQuery

```
jQuery('input')
```

This returns me an array of the Input tags. I can iterate through this and disable each and every one of them. But is there a better way to perform this operation. Something like,

```
jQuery('input').disable()
```

Comment: the form buttons will still be active if someone browses without javascript enabled, keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) it works on collections.

```
jQuery('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
$('input').attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: so sweet!!! Thanks for your instant response!!! This answer does not work. But this worked `jQuery('input').attr('disabled', true);` Can you please edit your answer to reflect this. I will then accept it.

Comment: This is going to give you every single input element on the form.  If you are only trying to disable submit buttons how about trying:  $("input[type='submit']").attr('disabled', true);

Answer (score 2):

You can do it efficiently and easily without jQuery:

```
var inputs = document.body.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; ++i) {
    if (input.type == "submit") {
        inputs[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no intrinsic `disable` function.  In the book "Jquery In Action", they created `enable` and `disable` methods for the example on how to create a jQuery plugin, so I've just kept those and used them.